# DomDocument/DOMXPath - How to get HTML Dom element by itemprop and img src

Tags: php, dom, domdocument, domxpath

I am working on a script which is getting data from HTML DOM elements.

Here is my code:

```php
$url = 'http://www.sportsdirect.com/nike-satire-mens-skate-shoes-242188?colcode=24218822';
libxml_use_internal_errors(true); 
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTMLFile($url);

$xpath = new DOMXpath($doc);

$Name = $xpath->query('//span[@id="ProductName"]')->item(0)->nodeValue;

echo $Name;
```

This code is simply taking the text inside `<span id="ProductName"></span>`. I know how to get the data from elements with specific class or id.

I don't know how I can get the `src="http://adres-to-image.com/img.png"` (pure example) from image tag or how I can get elements which do not have id or class but have attribute like `itemprop`, for example `<div itemprop="name"></div>`

1. How can I get the image `src`?
2. How can I get elements with `itemprop`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your examples:

```
$xpath->query('//img/@src)->item(0)->nodeValue
```

**This means**

Select all src attributes of all img tags and get the value of the first

```
$xpath->query('//div/[@itemprop="name"])->item(0)->nodeValue
```

**This means**

Select all divs with itemprop attr equals name and get the value of the first.

Answer (score 2):

You just look for the attributes:

```
$url = 'http://www.sportsdirect.com/nike-satire-mens-skate-shoes-242188?colcode=24218822';
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTMLFile($url);

$xpath = new DOMXpath($doc);

$Name = $xpath->query('//div[@class="productImageSash"]');
foreach($Name as $element){
    $imgs = $element->getElementsByTagName('img');
    foreach($imgs as $img){
        $src = $img->getAttribute('src');
        echo $src;
    }

}
```

Output:

```
/images/sash/productsash_mustgo.png
```

The same with `itemprop` attribute, look for divs which have this attribute:

```
$Name = $xpath->query('//div');
foreach($Name as $element){
    $itemprop = $element->getAttribute('itemprop');
    if($itemprop){
        echo "found";
    }

}
```